# How to make 301 redirect from one website to another where the ending is different?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have 2 websites:

```
OLD one - https://www.old.example/en/

NEW one - https://new.example/en
```

Lastly, Google Search Console reported around 80 improperly redirected links for OLD website, i.e.:

```
https://www.old.example/en/?p=41310

https://www.old.example/en/?p=45659

https://www.old.example/en/?p=72785
```

In .htaccess of OLD page is inputted only code:

```
Redirect 301 / https://new.example/
```

which redirects above links from OLD page to i.e.

```
https://new.example/en/?p=62692
```

How can I correct it and i.e. expect to have in such cases always redirection to main page - `https://new.example/en`

Comment: Please post your current used .htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: The `Redirect` rule you implemented _should_ do what you ask. If it does not the the question is _why_ that does not work. For that you'd need to state what _exact_ message you get. And what _exactly_ happens if you request such a link. Please add that information to the question (not here as a comment). Thanks.

Comment: Is `/en/` the only URL-path at the old website?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the query string completely (without a stray `?` at the end) you'll need to use mod_rewrite instead.

For example, in the `.htaccess` at the old domain:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en)/ https://new.example/$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

*Aside:* Although this many-to-one redirect will likely be seen as a soft-404 by Google.

Comment: Thank you. The case is that I got a lot of 404 messages from Google Search Console for old website and if I use current implementation it only redirects to new domain but still ending of link is not valid.

Should I then tried your proposed? Or maybe those may disappear suddenly as Google bot will stop see it?